# Androidplot line not showing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, charts, androidplot

I followed the [Quickstart tutorial](http://androidplot.com/wiki/Quickstart) and used new `LineAndPointFormatter(Color.BLACK, Color.RED, Color.TRANSPARENT)` to draw my lines. The red vertices show up on my Android tablet but the black lines don't. What could be the issue?

I use the latest `Androidplot version (0.5.0)` and followed the tutorials exactly but modified the `lineandpointformatter` argument values.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this problem by removing hardware acceleration. This is achieved by going to the AndroidManifest.xml file and adding this line in the  tag:

```
    <android:hardwareAccelerated = "false">
```